# Recover last argument of the last command in bash' vi mode

Tags: bash, inputrc

When using bash's vi mode (set -o vi), is it possible to recover the last argument of the last executed command? This is done in emacs mode with <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, and I would like to do it in vi mode as well.

I know that bash provides `!$` and `$_`, but they are not expanded and I find quite dangerous to use them directly.

I've tried (with no success) some solutions I found on Stack Overflow about editing the `.inputrc` and adding:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-insert
"\e.": yank-last-arg
"\e_": yank-last-arg
```

I'm switching to vi mode in bash but I'm quite used to <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and it would be nice to be able to use it, or to find a quick & easy replacement.

EDIT: This question has been marked as a duplicate of a similar one that asks about how to recover last argument with Alt+S. I was asking specifically about ESC+. (it's the shortcut I'm used to and it is not covered by the other answer).

EDIT: To complement @chaos' solution: the following binding makes ESC+. (well, really '.') paste the last argument, but you lose Vi's dot (.) functionality:

```
bind -m vi-command ".":insert-last-argument
```

Comment: There's regularly features that are not supported by `bash`, but by `ksh`. This one too; `$_` is expanded in `ksh`. It might be worth a thought to switch to `ksh`; one gains not only many useful features but also a lot performance. And specifically `bash`'s (vi-mode) history functions are not solved in an acceptable way, specifically if compared to `ksh`. Recent `ksh` versions have even a `bash` compatibility mode - not that I'd suggest to use it, though. (Just a suggestion. I'm aware that Linux users often just use what GNU provides.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me it works when I add the following to my `.inputrc`:

```
$if mode=vi
"\e.":yank-last-arg
$endif
```

Then, when changing it in bash on the fly, the `.inputrc` must be read again:

```
set -o vi
bind -f .inputrc
```

Now, I can get the last argument with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

Comment: It works,but it inserts a space character before the argument. Is there any way to enable ESC + dot too? (It works now with ALT+S). In the other hand, I don't understand why .inputrc is not being read on each login :?

Comment: 1. .inputrc IS read at each login, but mode is not set to vi, and however when switching to that mode (set -o vi) the binding are overwritten. 2. It work with <esc>+<dot> in my case, too (it's the same escape sequence as <alt>+<dot>).

Comment: In my case, ESC + dot repeats the last command that modified the buffer (as '.' does in vim), because ESC returns to command mode and dot repeats what I wrote. So "ls -l<ESC>." writes "ls -lls -l" ...

Comment: I've marked your answer as "the solution" as I don't see a way that ESC + . can work because they are not pressed at the same time and they both have a meaning under Vi (return to command mode and repeat last action that modified the buffer), so I'm starting to think that ESC+. cannot work like in Emacs mode without losing Vi's . (dot) functionality. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using `_` (in normal mode) to do that.
I've found it documented here http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.txt .

It's easy to remember too:

- `$_` expands to the last argument
- `<Esc> + _` types it out

Comment: Thanks. ESC and then _ in an Spanish keyboard requires pressing Shift (Shift + - = _) but it's a good alternative :)

Comment: You're welcome. It's the same with the US keyboard layout.

Comment: Nice find. Looks like you can also use `Shift + Alt + -`